# C++ Using curly brackets in assignment of class variable

Tags: c++

When I declare a array in C++, I can use curly brackets like this :

```
int var[3] = {1, 2, 3};
```

Can I use curly brackets declare in class, like as operator overloading?
I mean, like this :

```
class example
{
private:
    int m_sum;
public:
    void operator{}(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        m_sum = a+b+c;
    }
    int get_sum()
    {
        return m_sum;
    }
}

int main()
{
    example ex = {1, 2, 3};
    std::cout << ex.get_sum() << endl; // prints 6
    return 0;
}
```

The code above is just my imaginary, but I want to use curly brackets as this code.

Comment: Why not `example ex(1,2,3)`?

Comment: @Evert because I want to get variadic parameters when I declare a class variable. Using stdarg.h may be good alternative, but it requires a parameter which is containing number of parameters. Curly brackets assignment dosen't need it, least when I declare pure C array.

Comment: @quantdev Thank you! I'm not sure now, but maybe this is exactly what I want.

Comment: Maybe you want a variadic constructor template then. `class example { template <class... Ts> example(Ts&&... vs); };` Initializer list only works if all arguments have the same type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might want a constructor taking an [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>

class example
{
private:
    int m_sum;
public:
    example(std::initializer_list<int> parameters)
    {
        m_sum = std::accumulate(std::begin(parameters), std::end(parameters), 0);
    }

    int get_sum() const
    {
        return m_sum;
    }
};

int main() {
    example e = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    std::cout << e.get_sum();
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac90b80c775fabc2)

---

Another approach is to use a variadic template constructor (I find it less readable, but it has the advantage of making your code generic : you can pass arbitrary elements to the constructor) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>

class example
{
private:
    int m_sum;
public:
    template <class... Ts> example(Ts&&... vs) : m_sum(compute_sum(vs...)) { }

    int get_sum() const
    {
        return m_sum;
    }

private:
    template<typename Ts1>
    Ts1 compute_sum(const Ts1& val) { return val; } // termination

    template<typename Ts1, typename... Ts>
    Ts1 compute_sum(const Ts1& arg1, const Ts&... args)
    {
        return arg1 + compute_sum(args...); 
    }
};
```

**[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f69d2c7a46b8c34)**

---

**Note:**

There is no `operator{}` in C++.

Comment: I tried to pass an array in your first code example. It didn't work. Is there any way to pass an array of integers to the constructor?

Comment: @Superman : you cannot do that with initializer list, they just serve as proxy for an array when list-initialization is possible, but you can add a constructor to make it work with any container, including arrays, see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/743c5b87642b4108)

Answer (score 3):

If you can use a modern C++ (e.g. C++11), you may use [std::initializer_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list). Most of modern compilers do support it, just add `-std=c++11` compilation flag